# Issue with Robolectric with new version of Google Play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, robolectric

I use Robolectric for unit tests, I have Google Play Services in my project. This worked fine, until yesterday, when Google Play Services updated to a new version. I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg$zze.zznn(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg$zzi.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

It seems the Shadow class is not called, GooglePlayServicesUtil is called giving the NullPointerException. Has anyone seen this?

I don't even use Google Play Services in the tests.

Comment: The NullPointerException is mostly when the class is not shadowed. When are you getting this error? Is it during the test case run or is it when your application config loads before the test?

Comment: I know it's not shadowed. There is a shadow class for GooglePlayServicesUtil, and as until yesterday it worked well, it was shadowed before yesterday. I tried to find out if Robolectric depends on a specific version of GPS, didn't find that.

Comment: I think you can report this in `Roblectric` issues [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues), or Android issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list)

Comment: ow, thanks. I had posted in the Robolectric group.

Comment: Any update on this? I am having same issue.

Comment: update in the robolectric issues page, link above.

Comment: @Christine, see my edited answer. I've found solution, finally!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added next workaround and it works fine:

1. Extract all *PlayServices'* related code to Utility class (in my case it is just Availability check):

   ```
   public class PlayServicesUtils {

       private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

       public static final int AVAILABLE = 1;
       public static final int ERROR_RESOLVABLE = 2;
       public static final int ERROR_UNRESOLVABLE = 3;

       @IntDef({AVAILABLE, ERROR_RESOLVABLE, ERROR_UNRESOLVABLE})
       @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
       public @interface PlayServicesAvailability {
       }

       @PlayServicesAvailability
       public static int checkPlayServices(@NonNull Activity activity) {
           GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
           int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
           if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
               if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                   apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
                   return PlayServicesUtils.ERROR_RESOLVABLE;
               } else {
                   CLog.e(Constants.TAG, "This device does not support Google Play services.");
                   return PlayServicesUtils.ERROR_UNRESOLVABLE;
               }
           }
           return PlayServicesUtils.AVAILABLE;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement shadow for this Utility class:

   ```
   @Implements(PlayServicesUtils.class)
   public class ShadowPlayServicesUtils {

       @Implementation
       @PlayServicesUtils.PlayServicesAvailability
       public static int checkPlayServices(@NonNull Activity activity) {
           return PlayServicesUtils.AVAILABLE;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add shadow to your test class (or to base level test class):

   ```
   @Ignore
   @RunWith(TestRunner.class)
   @Config(
           sdk = 18,
           constants = BuildConfig.class,
           shadows = {
                   ShadowPlayServicesUtils.class
           }
   )
   public abstract class BaseTest {
       // some code, maybe 
   }
   ```
4. Add your shadow to TestRunner's InstrumentationConfiguration creation:

   ```
   public class TestRunner extends RobolectricGradleTestRunner {
       public TestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
           super(klass);
       }

       @Override
       public InstrumentationConfiguration createClassLoaderConfig() {
           InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder builder = InstrumentationConfiguration.newBuilder();

           builder.addInstrumentedClass(PlayServicesUtils.class.getName());

           return builder.build();
       }
   }
   ```

**Original answer:**

I've found [similar issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1995) on Robolectric issue tracker and workaround which is provided there - works!

Just force success initialisation of Google Play Services:

```
@Before public void setUp() {
    // force success every time
    ShadowGooglePlayServicesUtil.setIsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS);
}
```

EDIT:

But there is another [issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2215) with Play Services 8.3 and 8.4. And this issue is still not fixed.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Till the time they resolve the issue with 8.4 version, this works great!

Comment: I am unable to use this solution as the latest robolectric changed the api so it won't compile (our tests depend on the new version). Here is my question about how to implement this with the new one, please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123570/

Comment: @Gabor I see that you were able to solve your issue. We are no longer working with Robolectric and switched to instrumentation tests instead, so I'm not able to help you with the latest version.